# how to parse links by class name using node.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

This server gets all links of google's first site:

```
var     http = require('http');
var qs = require('querystring');
var request = require("request");
var cheerio = require('cheerio');

http.createServer().listen(1337, "127.0.0.1");

function parsehl(body, callback){
    $ = cheerio.load(body);
    var result = '';

    links = $('a'); //jquery get all hyperlinks       ???????

    $(links).each(function(i, link){
        var hyperlink = '\n'+ $(link).attr('href');
        result = result + hyperlink  ;
    });

    callback(result);}

    request({uri: 'http://www.google.com/search?q=rio&start=00'  }, function (error, response, body) {
        console.log('url requested ') ;
        if (!error){
            parsehl(body,  function(result){
                console.log(result);
            });
        }
        else
        {   
            console.log(error);
        }
    });
```

This server gets the links by tag name **a**.
The links we need have the class name **l**  (looks like nr 1 but is an l like in little).
How can we get the links here by class name?
We maybe need just one line where we put the questionmarks.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
links = $('a.l');
```

?

Comment: thanks for the answer, yes we have tried that, not working for us

Comment: Well, you're definitely doing everything correctly, and that would be the way to do it. E.g. try $('a.gbmt') - you'll get a handful of results. For some reason, it looks as if that URL is returning different output when looking at it in a web browser and requesting it via request() in node - maybe google does some kind of user-agent sniffing, maybe its dependent on having a google cookie, etc.